# StarCraft II Ubuntu 14.04 installation for a noob

Tags: wine, games

I followed some online instructions for installing StarCraft II from [Installing StarCraft II on Ubuntu 14.04](http://nosuchthingastwo.com/starcraft-ii-on-ubuntu-14-04/) and then it was trying to download eurofixi.exe from an FTP site and not getting any response and having to repeat itself over and over with no success.

The game seems to have downloaded, but there's no executable file to run with Wine.

When I try to redownload the game to play it on Ubuntu 14.04, it gives me the option press play, and when I do this it loads the game in part, asks me to login to [Battle.net](http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/) (not giving me the option to play offline) and then goes pear-shaped.

In the last paragraph in the  Installing StarCraft II on Ubuntu 14.04 tutorial it said.

> If you encounter any other issues, check out the blog posts I mentioned previously for some tips. If those don't help you and Google fails you, head over to Ask Ubuntu and try to find help there.

Comment: Reviewers of this question can find a discussion about this question in Ask Ubuntu Meta [here](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15071/question-with-accepted-answer-is-being-close-voted-as-unclear-one-and-a-half-yea).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

StarCraft II can also be installed with another alternative method using the PlayOnLinux application from the default Ubuntu repositories.

There is a [PlayOnLinux installer script for StarCraft II](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/app-661-Starcraft_II_Wings_of_Liberty.html) at the PlayOnLinux website. Click the arrow next to the *Source code* heading to unfold the source code of the PlayOnLinux installer script for StarCraft II.

Visit the [Create a script for PlayOnLinux - Chapter 1: Getting to know Bash](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/dev-documentation-1.html) for instructions about how to run a PlayOnLinux installer script, including screenshots.

**Executing your script**

Save your script in gedit, right-click the script and select *Properties* -> *Permissions* tab -> put a check mark in the checkbox to the left of where it says *Allow executing file as program*, and then use the function *Run a local script* from the *Tools* menu of PlayOnLinux.

There is also a newer version of the PlayOnLinux installer script for StarCraft II that uses Wine 1.7 that is available on the same website. This update "fixes Battle.net crash and has better quality in-game". Wine 1.7 is not in the repositories for Ubuntu 14.04, however Wine 1.7 can be installed by adding this Launchpad PPA: [ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) to your software sources using the instructions found at that link. The version of Wine for Ubuntu 14.04 from this PPA is up-to-date enough (Wine 1.7.55) that the newer version of the PlayOnLinux installer script for StarCraft II can be used with it.

**Update**

In all currently supported versions of Ubuntu Wine>=1.7 is provided by the *wine-development* package. To install it open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install wine-development # installs Wine 4 in 19.04+
```

In Ubuntu 18.04 and later Wine can also be installed by installing the *wine-stable* package.

```
sudo apt install wine-stable # installs Wine 3 in 18.04
```

Comment: This hasn't worked yet, i'm in the process, but i'm grateful for your time mate. Thank you very much.

Comment: guys this seems to have worked.

Comment: When i run it through playonlinux, i click run, and it runs the game, however my mouse pointer disappears and it has trouble connecting to battle net.

Comment: when i double click on the battlenet icon on the desktop, it comes up with an error and shuts down

Comment: thanks for that. there is an updated one that i am now trying, which hasn't been approved by the team yet. I think you're right, it appears to be written for wine 1.7.19. I wish i didn't have to download the whole game again. 3rd time lucky i guess.

Comment: Wine 1.7 is not in the repositories for Ubuntu 14.04, however Wine 1.7 can be installed by adding this Launchpad PPA: [ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa?field.series_filter=trusty) to your software sources using the instructions found at that link.

Comment: wouldn't the script have sourced it for me?

Comment: If the script contained that it would have a line in it like: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa` or alternatively it might prompt you to install it yourself manually. Either way, it would still work OK if you added ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa before running the POL installer script.

Comment: [StarCraft remaster unveiled, and original SD version becomes free-as-in-beer](https://arstechnica.com/gaming/2017/03/starcraft-remaster-unveiled-and-original-sd-version-becomes-free-as-in-beer/). Original StarCraft version's patch to 1.18 will make it free

Answer (score 1):

I too have been working hard on hacking my way through this. I finally got the game to run when I figured out that my graphics card drivers weren't doing me any favors (literally) kill and or remove all your video card drivers and reinstall ones you're absolutely sure are correct. All the other workarounds that I tried wouldn't get me passed the launcher. For example going into wine to mess with `dbhelp`, running windowed at different resolutions, installing windows fonts and winetricks. After all of those it was my drivers. Something I thought was fine. When nothing works... start looking at what you only assumed was working.

For me, after installing drivers the game launches and plays, but there are block text bugs and blacked out portions of the screen. Now i'm trying all of those other things to get it working smoothly. I haven't tried play on linux yet and I'm going to check youtube. There was a good video on getting `hearthstone/SC2` working. Now that my drivers are what I think they are, I might have success with their advice this time.

As far as finding the executale... It just kind of showed up under `/program files/starcraft` although I swear I looked there before. Keep digging.

Answer (score 1):

I made it work. Here is how I did, you may need to adapt it.

1. Fix the mesa package for the Blizzard launcher in case of black screen:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   ```

   You might need to restart your X server for the changes to take effect.

   ```
   sudo restart lightdm
   ```
2. Fix OpenGL drivers if it's still bugged:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers 
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get upgrade
   ```
3. Create different overrides for different applications in wine settings (Configure Wine):

   - Create new -> choose `Battle.net.exe` -> libraries -> dbghelp (disabled) & msvcp100 (native, builtin)
4. Start the Blizzard launcher, go to the game settings, check "launch 32 bits client" for Starcraft II.
5. Start the game.

Comment: `dist-upgrade` upgrades your whole distribution. Beware.