# Starcraft 2 under wine

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I have tried many times to install Starcraft 2 into Ubuntu, but every time the battle.net launcher loads, it its in a weird shape. I don't know what to do to fix this and any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Look at [Starcraft 2 Ubuntu 14.04 Installation For a Noob](http://askubuntu.com/questions/502807/starcraft-2-ubuntu-14-04-installation-for-a-noob/502810#502810)

Comment: @karel After I followed the instructions on that page, I got the same warped battle.net launcher. The setup page for starcraft 2 is fine, as well as the login for the launcher. 

Here is another picture: http://postimg.org/image/ws57bwi03/

Thanks for the help.

Comment: BTW, you need some more rep to add pictures! There is your first +5, I've upvoted!

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem. For me the solution was to install the propietory drivers from Radeon AMD. Once installed and chosen in the software, and a quick restart, I have a normal start-up window.

To install the proprietary graphics driver open the terminal and type:

```
ubuntu-drivers devices
```

The results of running this command will show you the package name of the recommended proprietary graphics driver. Then you can install it using the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install package-name-of-the-recommended-graphics-driver    
sudo reboot
```

Comment: How do I do this? Can we have some more detail in this post?

Comment: Would it not be better for an inexperienced user to be directed to `Software & Updates` and click on `Additional Drivers`?

Comment: When I run ubuntu-drivers devices, there is no output. Also, when I go to Software & Updates and click on Additional Drivers it says on the bottom "No proprietary drivers in use" and in the middle "No additional drivers available"

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know it's definitely because of your graphic card or it's drivers. 
I did not find any complete fix, but You can try this: http://www.webupd8.org/2014/10/partial-workaround-for-black-distorted.html?m=1 .
For me personally - while using Intel graphics - it made launcher looks good, but games began to work so horribly that I decided to leave it.
Keep in mind that this launcher distortion does not affect games and it still works normally so it can be better and easier to just learn how to click "play" even if you don't really see it or at least it does not look well.